# Getting cmd error because my windows username has spaces in it

Tags: cmd, spaces

[image: cmd screenshot]

I am following [this](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg) git repository Windows + Anaconda installation guide. I have downloaded the zip folder in my PC while running the command I am getting an Error

> pyrcc5 -o "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\labelImg-master\libs\resources.py"
> "C:\Users\DANIA NIAZI\labelImg-master\resources.qrc"

I have tried adding quotation marks %userprofiles% but nothing has worked

the error I am getting is:
**'C:/Users/DANIA' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

this is the files in the folder
[image: folder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with pyqt5 I have installed it using conda but when I installed in my default system the command worked perfectly.

Also I have installed all the requirements again using pip in virtual environment that is  pyQt5 and lxml